Multiple router network randomly freezes
I have a network with three ASUS routers.
The first router A was set up as the primary connected to the ISP.  This router was set up in Wireless router mode.
The next two ASUS routers (B and C) were set up in AP (Access Point) mode.  All had DHCP Server enabled.  The routers are at least a quarter mile apart from each other.  They are connected via a Ubiquiti dish network.
With the ISP modem connected directly to Router A the network was working fine.  We then had to move to a new ISP.  They required that we install their router “D” as the primary router.  Their modem/router is a Pace 5269ac.  I connected router A to Router D.  B and C routers did not change.  I now have a problem where the network “freezes” periodically.
Only a power off of routers A and D fix the freeze but only temporarily.  Router D is provided by the ISP vendor. I have limited change capability with router D.  I have full change access to Router A.  The Ubiquiti antennas have static IP addresses.  Router B and C have a static LAN IP address.  Router A is DHCP.  The gateway address in Routers A, B and C points to router D.
Questions:

Should I now change the configuration of router A to AP mode.

Should I turn off DHCP in routers A,B and C, and allow Router D to handle assignment of IP addresses?

Any other suggestions for this configuration?



Is router D connection to router A done via a LAN or WAN port of A? Is router D also a DHCP server? How are routers B and C having DHCP server capacity when configured as AP and why? Is it the intention to segment the local network into disjointed and unconnectable segments?

So what access do you have to D? Also, does D allow Subnet Mask cycling? In the network, does B link to C, or does A link to B and C separately?
